# Como convertir numeros en letras con laravel

Tags: laravel

Saludos a toda la comunidad. Mi pregunta es como poder covertir numeros en letras.

Por ejemplo, en un vista de mi pagina, se visualiza asi:

`importe total : 500,00`

y quiero poder visualizar de esta forma:

`importe total : 500,00
              son  : QUINIENTOS CON 00/100 BS.`

---

Encontré algo para laravel pero ahora tengo este error

> FatalErrorException in 7b1f6f9648ea381a95849de23c71a74d line 10: Class 'NumeroALetras' not found

Segui esta guia q encontre y quise adaptarla a lo q estoy haciendo pero no me salio, asi que necesito de su ayuda

Esta es la guia que encontré:

Instalación
Instala este paquete mediante Composer:

```
composer require luecano/numero-a-letras
```

Uso

Agregar la referencia a la libreria use NumeroALetras\NumeroALetras; en nuestro archivo PHP.

> ```
> Usar la función NumeroALetras::convertir($number, $currency, $upper) para convertir un número a letras.
> ```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use NumeroALetras\NumeroALetras;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return NumeroALetras::convertir(99.99, 'soles');
        // return NumeroALetras::convertir(99.99, 'pesos', false);
        // return NumeroALetras::convertir(1230.02, 'euros');
        // return NumeroALetras::convertir(38230.44, 'dólares');
    }
}
```

Y así es como traté de implementarlo a mi proyecto:

`controlador FacturasController`

La función show donde estoy guardando toda la información de un registro antes de mandarlo a una vista.

```
use NumeroALetras\NumeroALetras;

class FacturasController extends Controller
{
     public function show($cod_liquidacion)
     {
         $code_liq = \IMSUR\transpor::where('cod_liquidacion', $cod_liquidacion)->firstOrFail();
         return \View::make('transportes.show')->with('code_liq',$code_liq);    
     }
```

`vista show.blade.php`

Vista donde visualizo la info del registro selecionado con la funcion show de arriva.

```
<body>        
    <ul>
        <li> Nombre de usuario: {{ $code_liq->nombre_completo }} </li>
        <li> Email: {{ $code_liq->trans_1 }} </li>
        <li> fecha {{ $code_liq->fecha_ingreso }}</li>        
        <li>son: {{ NumeroALetras::convertir($code_liq->trans_1,'Bs.') }}</li>   // como lo intento adaptar al ejemplo encontrado    
   </ul>
```

Estaré aguardando sus respuestas. Gracias.

Answer (score 4):

**RESPUESTA MEJORADA NUEVA LIBRERIA**:

Investigando un poco los paquetes del composer en https://packagist.org

Encontre otra libreria para convertir numeros a letras, esta da soporte para colocar moneda y caracteres mayuscula sostenidos.

https://packagist.org/packages/luecano/numero-a-letras

Los pasoS para su instalacion y prueba en Laravel 5.8 son los siguientes:

**1) Desde la consola de comando ubicándonos en la ruta de nuestro proyecto en Laravel tipeamos el siguiente comando composer:**

```
composer require luecano/numero-a-letras
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2) Crear una ruta para probar la librería en el archivo web.php**

```
//ruta para libreria luecano/numero-a-letras
Route::get('numeroLetras', 'NumeroLetrasController@index');
```

**3) Crear un controlador para la librería NumeroLetrasController.php**

```
php artisan make:controller NumeroLetrasController
```

**4) Editar el controlador NumeroLetrasController.php para colocar el siguiente codigo:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use NumeroALetras\NumeroALetras;  //llamando la clase 

class NumeroLetrasController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo '4599.99 => ' . NumeroALetras::convertir(4599.99, 'soles') .'<br>';
        echo '78099.99 => '. NumeroALetras::convertir(78099.99, 'pesos', false) .'<br>'; //en minusculas
        echo '10230.02 => '. NumeroALetras::convertir(10230.02, 'euros') .'<br>';
        echo '38230.44 => '. NumeroALetras::convertir(38230.44, 'dólares') .'<br>';

    }
}
```

**5) Probamos el código:**

En mi ejemplo la ruta de mi proyecto es:

http://localhost/doblelogin/public/numeroLetras

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Anterior libreria llamada **NumberToLetters** que se encuentra en **composer** y puede implementarse en **Laravel**.

Aqui te coloco los paso para incluirla en el proyecto:

Links:

https://packagist.org/packages/ichavez/number-to-letter

https://github.com/ivanchavez01/NumberToLetters

Se ha probando en Laravel 5.8

**PASO 1.**

Para cargar el paquete tipeando la siguiente línea en la consola desde la ruta que se encuentra el proyecto en Laravel:

```
composer require ichavez/number-to-letter
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PASO 2.**

Crear un controlador

```
php artisan make:controller PruebaNumerosLetras
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Paso 3.**

Crear una ruta de pruebas en el archivo web.php

Agregar esta línea al final del archivo.

```
Route::get('numerosletras', 'PruebaNumerosLetras@index');
```

**Paso 4.**

Integrar la librería en el controlador para una prueba.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use NumberToLetter\NumberToLetter;

class PruebaNumerosLetras extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $numero ="12530.50";
        $salida = NumberToLetter::convert($numero);
        return   $numero . '<br> en Letras es: <br>' . $salida;
    }
}
```

**Donde:**

Aquí se indica el uso de la clase/ librería

```
use NumberToLetter\NumberToLetter;
```

Este es un ejemplo básico para mostrar el funcionamiento.

```
 public function index()
    {
        $numero ="12530.50";
        $salida = NumberToLetter::convert($numero);
        return   $numero . '<br> en Letras es: <br>' . $salida;
    }
```

**La salida es la siguiente:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> La librería no incorpora configuración de moneda por lo que deberá cambiar el resultado de la moneda en la salida usando el comando php. `str_replace()`

Comment: holas chaval el ejemplo muy bueno pero ya lo habia encontrado tb lo ultimo q publicaste , quise adecuarlo a lo q estoy realizando pero me sale un error de que no se encontro la clase , si lo quieres ver esta ahora en la actualizacion de mi pregunta añadi mas, la parte del codigo q estaba haciendo  pero no me sale

Answer (score 2):

Crea la siguiente clase en la carpeta App

```
    <?php



    namespace App;

class NumerosEnLetras

{

    private static $UNIDADES = [

        '',

        'un ',

        'dos ',

        'tres ',

        'cuatro ',

        'cinco ',

        'seis ',

        'siete ',

        'ocho ',

        'nueve ',

        'diez ',

        'once ',

        'doce ',

        'trece ',

        'catorce ',

        'quince ',

        'dieciseis ',

        'diecisiete ',

        'dieciocho ',

        'diecinueve ',

        'veinte '

    ];



    private static $DECENAS = [

        'venti',

        'treinta ',

        'cuarenta ',

        'cincuenta ',

        'sesenta ',

        'setenta ',

        'ochenta ',

        'noventa ',

        'cien '

    ];



    private static $CENTENAS = [

        'ciento ',

        'doscientos ',

        'trescientos ',

        'cuatrocientos ',

        'quinientos ',

        'seiscientos ',

        'setecientos ',

        'ochocientos ',

        'novecientos '

    ];



    public static function convertir($number, $currency = '', $format = false, $decimals = '')

    {

        $base_number = $number;

        $converted = '';

        $decimales = '';



        if (($base_number < 0) || ($base_number > 999999999)) {

            return 'No es posible convertir el numero en letras';

        }



        $div_decimales = explode('.',$base_number);



        if(count($div_decimales) > 1){

            $base_number = $div_decimales[0];

            $decNumberStr = (string) $div_decimales[1];

            if(strlen($decNumberStr) == 2){

                $decNumberStrFill = str_pad($decNumberStr, 9, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

                $decCientos = substr($decNumberStrFill, 6);

                $decimales = self::convertGroup($decCientos);

            }

        }



        $numberStr = (string) $base_number;

        $numberStrFill = str_pad($numberStr, 9, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        $millones = substr($numberStrFill, 0, 3);

        $miles = substr($numberStrFill, 3, 3);

        $cientos = substr($numberStrFill, 6);



        if (intval($millones) > 0) {

            if ($millones == '001') {

                $converted .= 'un millon ';

            } else if (intval($millones) > 0) {

                $converted .= sprintf('%smillones ', self::convertGroup($millones));

            }

        }



        if (intval($miles) > 0) {

            if ($miles == '001') {

                $converted .= 'mil ';

            } else if (intval($miles) > 0) {

                $converted .= sprintf('%smil ', self::convertGroup($miles));

            }

        }



        if (intval($cientos) > 0) {

            if ($cientos == '001') {

                $converted .= 'un ';

            } else if (intval($cientos) > 0) {

                $converted .= sprintf('%s ', self::convertGroup($cientos));

            }

        }



        if($format){

            if(empty($decimales)){

                $valor_convertido = number_format($number, 2, ',', '.') . ' (' . ucfirst($converted) . '00/100 '.$currency.')';

            } else {

                $valor_convertido = number_format($number, 2, ',', '.') . ' (' . ucfirst($converted) . $decNumberStr . '/100 '.$currency.')';

            }

        }else{

            if(empty($decimales)){

                $valor_convertido = ucfirst($converted) . $currency;

            } else {

                $valor_convertido = ucfirst($converted) . $currency. ' con ' . $decimales . $decimals;

            }

        }



        return $valor_convertido;

    }



    private static function convertGroup($n)

    {

        $output = '';



        if ($n == '100') {

            $output = "cien ";

        } else if ($n[0] !== '0') {

            $output = self::$CENTENAS[$n[0] - 1];

        }



        $k = intval(substr($n,1));



        if ($k <= 20) {

            $output .= self::$UNIDADES[$k];

        } else {

            if(($k > 30) && ($n[2] !== '0')) {

                $output .= sprintf('%sy %s', self::$DECENAS[intval($n[1]) - 2], self::$UNIDADES[intval($n[2])]);

            } else {

                $output .= sprintf('%s%s', self::$DECENAS[intval($n[1]) - 2], self::$UNIDADES[intval($n[2])]);

            }

        }



        return $output;

    }

}
```

Luego desde el controlador la incluyes

```
use App\NumerosEnLetras;
```

Luego la usas

```
$letras_total=NumerosEnLetras::convertir($operaciones->total,'Pesos',false,'Centavos');
```

Retorna el numero en Texo con la unidad de Pesos y centavos para los decimales